# Why does Xcode console print constraint ambiguity warnings but UI debugger doesn't?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell, it looks like this, nothing complex:

[image]

Constraints are:

1. Horizontally, all spacings are 16
2. Vertically, all spacings are 16: male.top = 16, male.bottom = 16, female.centerY = male.centerY, other.centerY = female.centerY
3. Widths of buttons are equal: female.width = male.width, other.width = female.width
4. Heights of buttons are equal to 35, male.height = 35, female.height = male.height, other.height = female.height

Code for this is:

```
for button in [maleButton, femaleButton, otherButton] {
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(button)
}

var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[male]-16-[female]-16-[other]-16-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["male": maleButton, "female": femaleButton, "other": otherButton]
)

constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-16-[male(35)]-16-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["male": maleButton]
)

constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: femaleButton,
        attribute: .height,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: maleButton,
        attribute: .height,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: femaleButton,
        attribute: .width,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: maleButton,
        attribute: .width,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: femaleButton,
        attribute: .centerY,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: maleButton,
        attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: otherButton,
        attribute: .height,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: femaleButton,
        attribute: .height,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: otherButton,
        attribute: .width,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: femaleButton,
        attribute: .width,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: otherButton,
        attribute: .centerY,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: femaleButton,
        attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

The warning message in console is:

[image]

**However, when I try to use UI Debugger, no run time constraint ambiguity warning is raised, why? Should I worry about this warning message in console?**

Comment: Xcode is not amazingly clear when it comes to talking about the problems in constraints. The rule of thumb is that every item must somehow declare their height, width, location on the x-axis and location on the y-axis.

I note with your description that you have specified the horizontal spacing, but you haven't said that they ought to be centered in the window, or to one side, or whatever.

Comment: @HackSaw He has mentioned vertical spacing for one button. That should be enough. My question is - are these constraints laid out relative to the `contentView` of the table view cell? Also, why not use a `UIStackView` for this?

Comment: I second the use of UIStackView, for whatever that's worth. :) It made me much happier.